# File upload with Activeadmin Rails using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I use Active admin as my rails application backend. I want to make a file upload. How can I accomplish this functionality?

Comment: I've never used Active Admin specifically, but the Paperclip gem helps you easily upload files and attach them to any model. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I found a way to use Paperclip with Active Admin.

I added this code in my model "Event" :

```
has_attached_file :map, :styles => { :medium => "238x238>", 
                                   :thumb => "100x100>"
                                 }
```

And i did this for my admin model :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
 form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
   f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :continent
    f.input :event_type
    f.input :name
    f.input :title
    f.input :content
    f.input :date_start, :as => :date
    f.input :date_end, :as => :date
    f.input :place
    f.input :map, :as => :file
    f.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:medium))
    f.input :userfull_info
    f.input :price
    f.input :phone, :as => :phone
    f.input :website, :as => :url
  end
  f.buttons
 end
end
```

To use it on the index page, you have to use :

```
column "Image" do |event|
    link_to(image_tag(event.image.url(:thumb), :height => '100'), admin_event_path(event))
  end
  default_actions
end
```

Comment: You can use f.input :image, :hint => "current image: #{f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))}"

Comment: Will this upload to s3 by default using paperclip?

Comment: I had to use "f.actions", not "f.buttons" to get this to work.

Comment: This seems great, but it doesn't preview the image if you just selected it and didn't upload the image yet. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Got it worked for Rails 4.1 and Paperclip 4.1:

**Model**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :thumbnail, :styles => { :medium =>     "300x300#", :thumb => "200x200#" }
validates_attachment :thumbnail, content_type: { content_type:     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }

end
```

**Admin Model**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Hotel do

permit_params :name, :description, :price, :thumbnail

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Project Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :thumbnail, :required => false, :as => :file
    # Will preview the image when the object is edited
  end
  f.actions
 end

show do |ad|
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    row :thumbnail do
      image_tag(ad.thumbnail.url(:thumb))
    end
    # Will display the image on show object page
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I got `paperclip NoHandlerError` and I had to `form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|`

Comment: @givanse you had to do `form :html ...` where?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the rails 3.0.1 and the following code

```
f.input :image, :hint => "current image: #{f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))}"
```

return a string. After search a solution, i found it.

```
f.input :image, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))
```

Send direct the object, will return a image to the html

Comment: You can use the first line of code, just call `html_safe` on the string (after the double quotes).

Answer (score 5):

In latest Version of ActiveAdmin & Rails 6 for displaying the file field we need to use the below code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  permit_params :name, :uploads
  

  form multipart: true do |f|
    f.inputs "Project Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :uploads, as: :file, required: false
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

In some old version of AA following code also worked.

f.input :uploads, required: false

Comment: Doesn't work, you still have to add as: :file in rails 6