# Capture customer uploaded image in admin dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

In my application, I am using [activeadmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) and [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)(for uploading images).
I have below code in `admin/customer.rb`

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
  index do
    column :first_name
    column :email
    column :phone
    column :address
    column :created_at
    column :avatar
  end
end
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far...?

Comment: I didn't try anything , i am very new to ruby on rails. just i added avatar column to customer.rb

Comment: In this Srack Overflow question complete steps are mentioned refer  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078107/file-upload-with-activeadmin-rails-using-paperclip

Answer (score 0):

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
  index do
    column :first_name
    column :email
    column :phone
    column :address
    column :created_at
    column :avatar do |customer|
      image_tag(customer.avatar.url(:thumb))
    end
  end
end
```